# python OpenCV(3.4.2) error: (-215:Assertion failed)

Tags: python, opencv

Hola estoy intentando usar los descriptores SIFT para la coincidencia de imágenes. Estoy planeando hacer coincidir una imagen con otra.

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)
index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
search_params = dict()
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)
```

pero me saca el siguiente error:

```
<ipython-input-6-1f81512d446c> in AlgSift(imagen, imagentocompare, umbral)
   21     search_params = dict()
   22     flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
---> 23     matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)
   24 
   25 

   error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /io/opencv/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:487: error: 
   (-215:Assertion failed) (size_t)knn <= index_->size() in function 
   'runKnnSearch_'
```

si me pueden ayudar a saber el porque, gracias